# Automatically generated user id

Tags: iphone

I am making an iphone application in which there is use of database. I want that whenever user put his or her information, there should be unique id no for each user. But this id no should generate automatically.

How can I do this..please help me.

Thanks alot.

Comment: Are you using Core Data or sqlite?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a unique ID by doing this:

```
NSString *uniqueID = [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] globallyUniqueString];
NSLog(@"%@", uniqueID);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you will be using SQLite for your database specific, you could make use of the auto increment present in SQLite for generating id automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the following example.

http://iosdevelopertips.com/general/create-a-universally-unique-identifier-uuid.html

this generated string + number unique string.

If you want only numbers then i guess you have to use current timestamp + some auto-generated random number string.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer you to use uuid for each user. If you don't know about uuid check it may be this will fulfill your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

see if this answer [How to save a video taken from camera into sqlite database in iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223762/how-to-save-a-video-taken-from-camera-into-sqlite-database-in-iphone/6224907#6224907) helps.
You can certainly take the unique Id generation from that link.